# Replace all "\n" with "," using tr leaves a % at the end of the line, what is it?

Tags: unix, tr

Replace all "\n" with "," using tr leaves a % at the end of the line,

I have a file created in vi

```
name1
name2
name3
```

When I run the following
`cat test.txt| tr "\n" ","`
I get `name1,name2,name3,%`

Could someone explain why it does appear

When I convert it to ascii codes i see

`cat test.txt | tr "\n" "," | od -An -t uC`

`110  97 109 101  49  44 110  97 109 101  50  44 110  97 109 101 51  44`

Comment: That's your shell telling you there's no newline at the end of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shawn mentioned this is just the shell showing there is no new line at the end of the output